# C#, JSON.net Loop through and store Jobject objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

New to both C# and to using JSON. Trying to make something that works with some JSON from a web API in the following format. Would like to loop through and store the secondUser_id and and the status for later use.

```
{
  "user_list": [
    {
      "user_id": "12345678910",
      "secondUser_id": "5428631729616515697",
      "member_since": "1521326679",
      "member_since_date": "2018-03-32",
      "function": "test",
      "rank_int": "1",
      "status": "0"
    },
    {
      "user_id": "11345638910",
      "secondUser_id": "5428631729616515697",
      "member_since": "1521326679",
      "member_since_date": "2018-03-32",
      "function": "test",
      "rank_int": "1",
      "status": "0"
    },
    {
      "user_id": "13452578910",
      "secondUser_id": "12390478910",
      "member_since": "12316578910",
      "member_since_date": "2018-03-32",
      "function": "test",
      "rank_int": "1",
      "status": "0"
    }
  ],
  "returned": 3
}
string jsonUrl = GetJSON("url");
JObject UsersJObject = JObject.Parse(jsonUrl);
JToken user = UsersJObject["user_list"].First["secondUser_id"];

Console.WriteLine("User ID: " + user);
```

This will get the first entry but I'm not sure what to use for a enumerator?

Comment: Consider deserializing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
foreach (var obj in UsersJObject["user_list"] as JArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj["secondUser_id"]);
}
```

You can iterate over elements of a JArray, and user_list will be of that type, cast it and you can iterate it in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`.

This can help you to use objects easily

```
public class UserList
{
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string secondUser_id { get; set; }
    public string member_since { get; set; }
    public string member_since_date { get; set; }
    public string function { get; set; }
    public string rank_int { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class JsonData
{
    public List<UserList> user_list { get; set; }
    public int returned { get; set; }
}
```

Use like this.

```
string jsonUrl = GetJSON("url");

JsonData UsersJObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(jsonUrl);

foreach (var obj in UsersJObject.user_list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.secondUser_id);
}
```